# Watir::browser in ruby - Catch all the XHR requests with their responses, made by browser

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, firefox, web-scraping, watir

I'm using following `gems` to open the site in the browser

```
gem "watir", "~> 6.1"
gem 'watir-scroll'
gem "geckodriver-helper"
gem 'chromedriver-helper'
```

I'm making an instance for the browser to operate on loaded `HTML` like,

```
browser = Watir::Browser.new :firefox
browser.goto "https://www.mysitessss.net/testing"
```

I just want to catch all the `XHR` requests made by this page URL after loading using the `browser` object, so I can get their responses.

Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The primary purpose of webdriver and tools like WATIR and capybara that sit on top of webdriver is to drive the browser the way a user would.  Deep inspection of the resulting network traffic is not really part of the tool.

To do this manually you can use the developer tools network tab to see all the requests that happen as the page is loaded.  You could also use network sniffing or proxy tools such as fiddler-2, Charles, Wireshark, or Netmon.

To do it programmatically you might want to use nokogiri or a similar gem that specializes in parsing html perhaps in combination with something like rest-client if you want to actually make requests of the various api endpoints and work with the XML/JSON returned by the services being called.   This blog posting might be helpful https://readysteadycode.com/howto-extract-data-from-html-with-ruby

Comment: It's not accurate to say WATIR and capybara sit on the top of webdriver, It's accurate to say WATIR and capybara sit on the top of Selenium and Selenium gives the command to the webdriver and according to the command it received, it drives the browser.

Comment: I would disagree.  the API that WATIR and Capybara call is the WEBDRIVER API. neither uses what some would call 'selenese'.  The Webdriver API was also added to selenium when it went to 2.0 and the Selenium and Webdriver projects merged.  Development of Selenium 2 (ruby) and what was called watir-webdriver happened in parallel.   (see http://watir.com/history/ )The current 'powered by selenium' branding is basically a result of the selenium name 'winning out' when those projects merged and selenium was re-written to run on top of webdriver.  See https://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp

Comment: why is this the accepted answer? This doesn't even answer the question.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this with:

```
script = 'var performance = window.performance || window.mozPerformance || window.msPerformance || window.webkitPerformance || {}; return performance.getEntries().filter(e=>e.initiatorType=="xmlhttprequest")'
browser.execute_script(script)
```